# Date formatting in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, date-formatting

I want to change is the date column from a format "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS" to "DD.MM.YYYY".

```
  <DataGrid Name="dgBuchung" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >
  <ab:DataGridTextColumn Header="Fecha Entrada" Width="110"  
       Binding="{Binding date, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        
</DataGrid>
```

Unfortunately that code throws an `XMLParseException`.

First of all, is this way of solution possible while using AutoGenerateColumns?
If no, how else can I try to handle this?

If yes, what is the problem with the code above?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Don`t forget to use DataGrid.Columns, all columns must be inside that collection.
In my project I format date a little bit differently:

```
<tk:DataGrid>
    <tk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <tk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StartDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss\}}" />
    </tk:DataGrid.Columns>
</tk:DataGrid>
```

With AutoGenerateColumns you won`t be able to contol formatting as DataGird will add its own columns.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that!
Is it possible to bind a Column to a field out of my database without having a property in my project?

Comment: @Harald, no, you cant bind directly to database field, first you have to make or generate some object (for example, using [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx)). If you already have a collection of such objects, then you can bind it to DataGrid.ItemsSource property, as you did in your code.

Comment: If StringFormat depends of Culture? For sample, En-US : dd.MM.yy , FR : dd-MM-yyyy, ES-es: dd/MM/yyyy, etc

Comment: @Kiquenet, if you have some custom format for every culture then you  better move that logic to Converter or property getter. Otherwise you can look into some more options with [custom date formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Converter or property getter samples ? _IMHO, better samples for minimize learning curve are real 

applications with full source code and good patterns_

Comment: What is that zero character doing in the string format? It's needed but I can't really figure out why. When I format normal strings in C# I usuall go *dateTime.ToString("dd MMM")* to get "08 Jul". But here it seems to be different and I'm unsure what to google for...

Comment: @KonradViltersten, it's an index for [string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is used when [StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is applied.

Comment: Like Terrence answered below, use {Binding StartDate, StringFormat=d} to use user's Short Date format.

Answer (score 116):

Very late to the party here but in case anyone else stumbles across this page...

You can do it by setting the AutoGeneratingColumn handler in XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"  ..etc.. />
```

And then in code behind do something like this:

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(System.DateTime))
        (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
}
```

Comment: Great! In case you need a VB.NET version: 

Private Sub MyGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(sender As Object, e As DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs) handles MyGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn
 If e.PropertyType = GetType(System.DateTime) Then
  TryCast(e.Column, DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
 End If
End Sub

Comment: (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "d";  // use Short Date format

Comment: Format date columns differently using e.PropertyName:  if (e.PropertyName == "Open_Date")  {(e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "d";}

Comment: you are a hero :) that was  exactly what i was searching for. though you won't have to add single collumns with bindings.

Comment: I would use `DataGridBoundColumn` instead of `DataGridTextColumn` to be more generic.

Answer (score 18):

If your bound property is DateTime, then all you need is

```
Binding={Property, StringFormat=d}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Was in need of formatting which doesn't interfere with system format.

Answer (score 8):

```
Binding="{Binding YourColumn ,StringFormat='yyyy-MM-dd'}"
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of your code, it will greatly increase the quality of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

first select datagrid and then  go to  properties find Datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn and the double click
And then use this code

```
   Datagrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.PropertyName == "Your column name")
                    (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "dd/MMMMMMMMM/yyyy";
                if (e.PropertyName == "Your column name")
                    (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "dd/MMMMMMMMM/yyyy";
            }
```

I try it it works on WPF

Comment: Although I'm using Mark Feldman for my project, your solution is very useful for those cases when you have different properties of the same type and you want different formats for each one.

Answer (score 1):

I know the accepted answer is quite old, but there is a way to control formatting with AutoGeneratColumns :

First create a function that will trigger when a column is generated :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGeneratedColumns="dataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns" Margin="116,62,10,10"/>
```

Then check if the type of the column generated is a DateTime and just change its String format to "d" to remove the time part :

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            if(YourColumn == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                e.Column.ClipboardContentBinding.StringFormat = "d";
            }
        }
```

Comment: That's what  Mark Feldman already answered.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question, but I found a new solution, so I wrote about it.

> First of all, is this way of solution possible while using AutoGenerateColumns?

Yes, that can be done with AttachedProperty as follows.

```xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
   local:DataGridOperation.DateTimeFormatAutoGenerate="yy-MM-dd"
   ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

### AttachedProperty

There are two AttachedProperty defined that allow you to specify two formats.
`DateTimeFormatAutoGenerate` for `DateTime` and `TimeSpanFormatAutoGenerate` for `TimeSpan`.

```cs
class DataGridOperation
{
    public static string GetDateTimeFormatAutoGenerate(DependencyObject obj) => (string)obj.GetValue(DateTimeFormatAutoGenerateProperty);
    public static void SetDateTimeFormatAutoGenerate(DependencyObject obj, string value) => obj.SetValue(DateTimeFormatAutoGenerateProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DateTimeFormatAutoGenerateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DateTimeFormatAutoGenerate", typeof(string), typeof(DataGridOperation),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => AddEventHandlerOnGenerating<DateTime>(d, e)));

    public static string GetTimeSpanFormatAutoGenerate(DependencyObject obj) => (string)obj.GetValue(TimeSpanFormatAutoGenerateProperty);
    public static void SetTimeSpanFormatAutoGenerate(DependencyObject obj, string value) => obj.SetValue(TimeSpanFormatAutoGenerateProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeSpanFormatAutoGenerateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TimeSpanFormatAutoGenerate", typeof(string), typeof(DataGridOperation),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => AddEventHandlerOnGenerating<TimeSpan>(d, e)));

    private static void AddEventHandlerOnGenerating<T>(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is DataGrid dGrid))
            return;

        if ((e.NewValue is string format))
            dGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += (o, e) => AddFormat_OnGenerating<T>(e, format);
    }

    private static void AddFormat_OnGenerating<T>(DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e, string format)
    {
        if (e.PropertyType == typeof(T))
            (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = format;
    }
}
```

### How to use

#### View

```xml
<Window
   x:Class="DataGridAutogenerateCustom.MainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridAutogenerateCustom"
   Width="400" Height="250">
   <Window.DataContext>
      <local:MainWindowViewModel />
   </Window.DataContext>
   <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="DEFAULT FORMAT" />
      <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Dates}" />

      <TextBlock Margin="0,30,0,0" Text="CUSTOM FORMAT" />
      <DataGrid
         local:DataGridOperation.DateTimeFormatAutoGenerate="yy-MM-dd"
         local:DataGridOperation.TimeSpanFormatAutoGenerate="dd\-hh\-mm\-ss"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Dates}" />
   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

#### ViewModel

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public DatePairs[] Dates { get; } = new DatePairs[]
    {
        new (){StartDate= new (2011,1,1), EndDate= new (2011,2,1) },
        new (){StartDate= new (2020,1,1), EndDate= new (2021,1,1) },
    };
}

public class DatePairs
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Span => EndDate - StartDate;
}
```

[demo_wpf_datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaMZs.png)