# How to show just the date and not date and time in a WPF datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, date, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid with a binding to a class object that looks like the following:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Date" Binding="{Binding OrderDate }" />
```

The property in the class is quite simple, as follows:

```
public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
```

When I'm populating this property I'm just sending `DateTime.Date` (date only, not time):

```
.Select(
    r =>
    new Customer
        {
            Persona = r.Persona,
            CustomerName = r.CustomerName,
            Email = r.Email,
            Organization = r.Organization,
            PhoneNumber = r.PhoneNumber,
            Street = r.Street,
            Suburb = r.Suburb,
            Postcode = r.Postcode,
            OrderDate = r.OrderDate.Date
        }))
```

Unfortunately this doesn't reflect in my WPF datagrid as that's showing the date, but then it's also showing the time (everywhere) as `12:00:00AM`. How should I approach just having my WPF datagrid show the date only?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Date" Binding="{Binding OrderDate , StringFormat=d}" />
```

more info on string formattings [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Alternately you can do it in the code:

```
((DataGridTextColumn)YourGridName.Columns[0]).Binding.StringFormat = "d";
```

(Credit: I got his information from Mark Feldman's answer to this question: [Date formatting in WPF datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978249/date-formatting-in-wpf-datagrid))