# What's the correct SQL query to retrieve date field without time? C# MS Access

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Microsoft Access Database with a Date column listing dates in the format MM/DD/YYYY. I'm using the query :

```
SELECT Date FROM Table
```

This returns the date in C# in the format MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS.

What would be the correct query to retrieve just the date and not the time?

Comment: you can process dateTime to Time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format date in MS Access you can use `FORMAT` function. In your case it will look like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(Date, 'Short Date') FROM Table
```

Edit: Note that above example returns date in short date format as it is set up in system settings. To be more specific you can also use custom format like `FORMAT(Date, 'yyyy/mm/dd'`).

Comment: Thank you so much! After hours of searches online, I finally found an answer.

Comment: I see that in comment to another answer you mention WPF. If you display data through bindings, you can just change it's display format in WPF and not bother formatting it in SQL query. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978249/date-formatting-in-wpf-datagrid

Answer (score 2):

You can just change it in C# by doing

```
yourDateTimeVariable.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean here with C#. But if you want the query to return it in that format, you could do something like

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t.Date, 101) FROM Table t
```

read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx about convert and it's formats.

If you want to have c# do it, you can use the DateTime.Format() see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have an Access Database and a C# program. I'm trying to grab data from the Date Column from the database and display it in C# WPF.

Comment: I think I understand. If you are simply excutingSql commands (no linq or anything) using c#, does the query I provided solve your problem?

Comment: The function Convert wasn't found it's giving me.

Comment: My apologies, I was somehow misread you were using Microsoft Access and thought of TSQL. It's Format instead of convert for Access

Answer (score 0):

In `C#` (since this question is tagged `C#`)

You have `Date` property of `DateTime` which returns `Date`.

```
var newdate = dateobject.Date;
```

or you can create new Date by passing date, month, year values to `DateTime` constructor.

```
var newdate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 0, 0, 0);
```

Please note, in both cases what you get is `DateTime` object with time set to `12:00 AM`. in `C#` there is nothing like `Date` only, it is always associated with time.