# WPF Datagrid Column showing a time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I got a database and a WPF form where I can display the data (and adapt it).

The problem is: if I want to adapt the column containing a time it looks like
06.00:00:00:00:00.....
which leads to an error.

how can I tell the WPF datagrid, that it is a time of the format HH:mm?

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="TableViewSource" Source="{Binding Source={x:Type Model:myTable}}"/>


<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="Test" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TableViewSource}}" Margin="10,13,10,10" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ID" Binding="{Binding myTableID}" Header="ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Weekday" Binding="{Binding Weekday}" Header="Weekday" Width="SizeToHeader"/>                 
     <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="StartColumn"  Binding="{Binding Start, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Starttime" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="EndeColumn" Binding="{Binding Ende, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Endtime" Width="SizeToHeader" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I think you can specify a format in wpf, inside your Binding statement

Comment: I tried 'Binding="{Binding Ende, Mode = TwoWay, StringFormat = 'HH:mm'}" ' Any ideas what my mistake is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date formatting in WPF datagrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978249/date-formatting-in-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<toolkit:DataGridTextColumn ... Binding="{Binding Ende, StringFormat = 'HH:mm'}"/>
```

2-way is not possible if I'm not mistake.
For 2-way binding you should use an `IValueConverter`