# C# disable autoformatting in SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, formatting

I'm using `SqlConnection`, `MySqlConnection` and `OracleConnection` in WPF to get content of tables in databases.

When I try to get the output from the table, everything works perfectly. But if any of the session attributes have a date type, it will automatically reformat from '2020-02-20' to '20/02/2020 12:00:00 AM 'and I would need that date to stay exactly as it is and to not format in all three types of databases. How can I prevent it from auto formatting?

It is possible that it does another type too, but I have not noticed.

In the command line, it returns the date values correctly as they were inserted into the table.

In SQL Server, I'm getting data like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      da.Fill(dt);
}

dataGrid.DataContext = dt;
```

Where `query` is string like `SELECT * FROM STUDENT`, and dataGrid is defined in XAML like this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"  x:Name="dataGrid" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Edited: When I load data to some Array or List it returns dates in format: `20.02.2020 0:00:00` which is also wrong.

Thank you

Comment: the issue is not in the database, but the formatting of the datagrid.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978249/date-formatting-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: @jdweng Are u sure? Because when I load data to some Array or List, it did the same.

Comment: How are you viewing the data?  DateTime are numbers that are stored and transferred in UTF.  The tool that is used to display the DateTime converts the number to a string using the culture of the machine (timezone and format).  So you are just looking at a converted string from a number.  Not the number that is stored.

Comment: I just had to formatted it back, when column type is Date using To.String("yyyy-MM-dd"). It's actually not what I wanted, but it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET simply does not have a data type for DATE, so the different database date and time types are all mapped to .NET's [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8), which "Represents an instant in time, typically expressed as a date and time of day."  And in this mapping a DATE is mapped to midnight on that day.

So while the SqlDataReader knows about the SQL Server data types, when you use a DataAdapter and load the data into a DataTable, all the data is translated from SQL Server types to .NET types.

You're going to get a DateTime at the client, and it's up to you to display it appropriately.  If you want to us a display format that doesn't show the time portion, you can.  EG

[Date formatting in WPF datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978249/date-formatting-in-wpf-datagrid)