# Error while converting string to datetime in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DateTime, i'm trying to convert it to string, then convert it back to DateTime to format it.
But i keep getting "string isn't recognized as valid datetime string".
Any ideas?

```
var data = list_2.Entries.Select(c => new clients { code = cli_code, last_backup = c.Name, last_backup_date = c.AsFile.ClientModified.ToLocalTime() }).LastOrDefault(); 
var last_backup_date = data.last_backup_date;
var last_backup_date_string = Convert.ToString(last_backup_date);
var last_backup_date_formatted = DateTime.ParseExact(last_backup_date_string, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var today_date = DateTime.Today;
```

Comment: Can you add value of `last_backup_date_string`?

Comment: yeah, sure, one min

Comment: i can put the output from the ```data.last_backup_date ``` if you'd like

Comment: we need to see an example of how last_backup_date  looks like

Comment: What is the actual datatype of `var last_backup_date = data.last_backup_date;` since you need to convert it to string with this line `Convert.ToString(last_backup_date);` ?

Comment: here:  data.last_backup_date {6/22/2020 10:03:40 AM}

Comment: @RandRandom it's DateTime

Comment: Well if it is of type `DateTime` in the first place, why do you need to first convert it to a `string` just to parse it back to a `DateTime`?

Comment: because i want to format it. It comes in the normal US standard. I want to format it to dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Judging from your variable names are you just simply looking for `var last_backup_date_formatted = data.last_backup_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a `DateTime`, you could just format it:

```
string s = last_backup_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

There is no need to first convert it to a `string` and then try to convert it back to a `DateTime`. A `DateTime` object itself has no specific format by the way.

Comment: yeah, but that leaves my datetime as a  string and thus i can't order it on my datagrid

Comment: What do you mean? How would convert it to and back from a string make any difference?

Comment: @MatthewAlmeida - than you need to apply the format of the datetime object on your datagridcolumn in winforms eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033113/how-to-format-datetime-columns-in-datagridview

Comment: You could format it in the `DataGrid` only if that's what you want.

Comment: @MatthewAlmeida - wpf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978249/date-formatting-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: @mm8 Straight forward, beat me to it.  Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

`Var last_backup_date_string = last_backup_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: the string formatted, but the datetime continues the same

Comment: @MatthewAlmeida: A `DateTime` object has no specific format...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have, the conversion should not be an issue.  However, the problem area is probably in your `ParseExact`.  Your current date format starts with month not the day.  You should be able to do the format to display in your preferred manner.

```
Console.WriteLine($"{date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")}");
Console.WriteLine($"{date.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")}");
Console.WriteLine($"{date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")}");
```

Otherwise you could use the `DateTime.Parse` method or `DateTime.TryParse` so you do not have to specify the culture variation.

Example:

```
DateTime date;
var current = DateTime.Now.ToString();
if(DateTime.TryParse(current, out date))
     Console.WriteLine(date);
```

---

```
DateTime date;
var current = "6/22/2020 10:03:40 AM";
if(DateTime.TryParse(current, out date))
     Console.WriteLine($"{date:dd/MM/yyyy}");
```