# How to edit datetime column in a dataset?

Tags: c#, datetime, dataset, datarow

My dataset has column ' START_DATE' and its in datetime format.

this is what i tried so far.

```
foreach (DataRow dR in codeDs.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var def_startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dR["START_DATE"].ToString());
    dR["START_DATE"] = def_startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

    var def_endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dR["END_DATE"].ToString());
    dR["END_DATE"] = def_endDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

However, this chunk of code is not updating the dataset.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Well you aren't really changing anything. First your read it, than you write the same data you have read into it, so basically you do nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. Could you advise what should i change?

Comment: sorry, but did you understand what I was saying? IMHO it is obvious what need to be changed, if you did. Not trying to be an ass, but I simply fail to understand what could be unclear. here a sample code dr[„START_DATE“] = DateTime.Now.ToString(); - in this sample I am using DateTime.Now you need to change it to whatever value it needs to be, but not as you are currently doing it with the same value already in dr[„START_DATE“]

Comment: i am just formatting the existing value there. Previously its a complete date time, now i am trying to remove the time portion.

Comment: Okay, now I understood your requirement, sorry about my confusion what your code is trying to achieve. IMHO you should drop your code and format the string representation of the datetime eg. if you are using the datatable/dataset in a wpf datagrid you can change the format for the binding to your need - have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978249/date-formatting-in-wpf-datagrid - you shouldn't try to alter the value inside the datarow but instead provide a proper formating to the control you display the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new column of string type to datatable. Add data through loop in your required format as "dd/MM/yyyy". in last you can delete old column.

Comment: Hi, i am exporting to Excel afterwards. 
I don't think this will work.